# Ant build failing, "idl2java: cannot execute binary file"

Tags: java, ant, jenkins, idl

I am using invoke `ant` in jenkins basic job build.
My build job is failing because it is not able to execute binary file.
In my `build.xml` file I have the syntax like,

```
<exec command ="${idl2java}
            ${idls_idlflags}
            ${idls_extraflags}
            ${idl.filenames}"
      failonerror="yes">
</exec>
```

All the arguments `${idl2java}`, `${idls_idlflags}`, `${idls_extraflags}`, `${idl.filenames}` are defined correctly. But in the console `enter code here`output I'm seeing:

> /bin/idl2java: cannot execute binary file

Comment: Permission problem ? 755 permissions present ?

Comment: The two asterisks `**` part of the command you want to execute? If so this might be the problem.

Comment: when i run the build in Linux it is working fine.. but when i run it from Jenkins, it is throwing error like this.

Comment: the asterisks ** here mean that path (**/**/**/idl2java: cannot execute binary file)

Answer (score 0):

check if the Linux user_id with which Jenkins job is executing the idl2java has permissions to access it.

Comment: The permission is "-r-xr-xr-x". But when I build in console it is running succesfully. When invoked from jenkins, I'm getting this error

Comment: check the file type. file command will give you the type. May be its a 32bit/64bit mismatch.